# where is the bluetooth 'dual-mode' definition?

Tags: bluetooth

I been reading through the Bluetooth 4.0 core specification. However, I cannot find anywhere which states the true definition of 'dual-mode'.

From other google results, it looks like 'dual-mode' means that a BT device that has this capability can communicate with a LE device and a BR/EDR device simultaneously. However, I cannot find any official bluetooth docs that states this feature.

The closest one that I can get is:

> The Brand book uses the term “dual mode” device to refer to a design
>   (host and/or controller) that is qualified in compliance with the
>   Basic Rate and Low Energy Combined Core Configuration as defined in
>   the Bluetooth specification. It is also referred to in the Bluetooth
>   specification as a BR/EDR/LE design.

from [here](https://bluetooth.service-now.com/ess/knowledge.do?sysparm_document_key=kb_knowledge,8fbb115c4f12020010d301b28110c787)

Could someone point out the location where 'dual-mode' is defined?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is some different logic.

> The two most prevalent implementations of the specification are
>   Bluetooth Basic Rate/Enhanced Data Rate (BR/EDR), which was adopted as
>   version 2.0/2.1, and Bluetooth with low energy (LE), which was adopted
>   as version 4.0/4.1/4.2. Each implementation has different use cases
>   and each implementation uses a different chipset to meet essential
>   hardware requirements. Dual-mode chipsets are also available for
>   applications that include both use cases. https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification

There is Bluetooth 2.x - BR/EDR spec and there is Bluetooth 4.x (now 5.0). They are individuals specification with different purposes and different tech implementation (different modulation, different DSP blocks, different modes of work, etc). Manufacturer like TI, STM and so on just implement both of theese specs on one chip (System on Chip) or in SiP (System in Package). And **theese SoC and SiP named "dual-mode devices" and often BT 2.0 and BT 4.x work in theese SoCs (SiPs) simultaneously.**